# Anti-aliasing of ID Mask is more coarse than Cryptomatte

Tags: compositing-nodes, antialiasing, id-mask, cryptomatte

The edges of the Cryptomatte are smooth, but the edges of the ID Mask are rough even if the anti-aliasing option is checked.
The anti-aliasing option of ID Mask seems to have a very small difference between on and off.

How can I make the ID Mask's anti-aliasing as smooth as Cryptomatte?

[image]

I've attached the blend file I set below.
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: You can use *Blur*, *Dilate/Erode* nodes in different variations to smooth it. But it will be still worse than cryptomatte.

Comment: I don't think there is any decent, that is why cryptomatte became "game changer" (with som eissues as well, as you can see). You can play with edge in composite, but it always brings some artefacts (inaccuracy) in final comp.

Comment: @vklidu
I understood the limitations of ID masks.
However, the issue of edge artifacts in Cryptomatte remains.
Please review the additional questions on the [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164671/i-get-border-artifacts-when-using-cryptomatte-or-id-mask?noredirect=1#comment278173_164671).

Comment: I already commented there :) few hours ago  :) see the link there. And I know you know about ID, but you are looking for answer and I think there is not any for ID (except what I and Serge where mentioned).

Comment: @vklidu Oh! I was hasty. There was already your comment. In the meantime, I searched for hours and got a conclusion. The border expansion technique is inevitable and doesn't use matte as raw. As an alternative, it is assumed that you should use viewlayers or look at deepEXR. Or bringing the work of the fusion guys into the blender.

Comment: If the antialiased pixels are completed, the emissions are intertwined along the edge. In theory, assuming you know the exact antialiasing approach, and have a non-antialiased version of the foreground element and background, it would be feasible to separate the emissions for a clean edge.

Comment: @troy_s Is there a name for that technique? I want to search. Or let me know if there is a video or topic link.

Comment: If you can get the plates, we could probably demo it here. It is basic light emission concepts. To peel the mixed emissions along that edge apart, you need to know exactly how they are mixed in the anti-aliased edge so that you can replicate it perfectly without the foreground or background element. The brute force way would seem to be a pass with no AA for both elements, and a pass with. That should be enough information I think? Speculating, so need a test.

Comment: @troy_s It's a bit understandable .. But the concept is unfamiliar to me and I'm not native to English, so textual commentary alone doesn't give me a sense of what I should be doing in Blender. It would be great if i could see the visuals.

Comment: We would need non-anti-aliased output. I'm not sure Blender can deliver it. Your English is better than mine, and it's the only language I speak.

Comment: @troy_s good. I'm sorry I made you repeat the same thing. Blender can output non AA images. Just set the filter value on the film tab to 0. But I'm away from work for a while, so next week I'll attach a non-AA image at the bottom of this topic and I'll wait for your further instructions.

Comment: I thought the AA was limited to 0.01? We would need four plates I believe. 1. Foreground no AA 2. Background no AA 3. Foreground AA 4. Mix with AA.

Comment: @troy_s Hi troy_s, I'm back. I prepared the four plates you asked for at the bottom of the topic. What is next step?

Comment: You have several issues here. First is that a JPEG has crosstalk due to compression. You'd need uncompressed plates. EXRs would work. Second, you've composited against full emission backdrops. That's contaminating the edges. You want no emission backdrops for this to even have a hope. Third, if your goal were to isolate the grey objects, you provided the wrong plates; the grey object is "foreground" to the magenta, for example.

Comment: @troy_s I will answer you on several issues.
1. When I upload an image to Blender Stack Exchange, JPEG conversion happens automatically.
2. I actually have a clean PNG with transparency. If you want, i can render the EXR and proceed to the next step.
3. Sorry for the confusion. In this demonstration, let's proceed to separating the turquoise objects.
Please guide me through the following steps.

Comment: I spoke to some others and it sounds like the ID / Cryptomatte is some artificial AA, not the AA in the beauty passes, so the idea won’t work. Basically garbage that can’t be fixed sadly. Sorry.

Comment: @troy_s Fine. Thank you for continuing the conversation over the last few days. These failure cases can further improve my understanding of ID / Cryptomatte. I find Cryptomatte a big advantage, but at the same time there are limitations. In blenders, Cryptomatte is great to use for make ups with a little color correction, but it's hard to deal with excessive color variations.

Comment: It's unfortunate because in theory it would be entirely feasible to do what you are hoping to do. I suspect it would require deep pixels and the ability to set the Cryptomatte / ID in during path tracing. Otherwise it's impossible to unbundle the emissions perfectly, which is what you are attempting to do. The math to peel the emissions apart would be very easy, but it simply isn't possible due to how the Cryptomatte / ID generates AA differently to the final product.

Comment: @troy_s I would like to learn math to peel the emissions irrespective of the ID Mask / Cryptomatte. Can you guide me a little bit more? I want to finish our demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted answers both [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164671/i-get-border-artifacts-when-using-cryptomatte-or-id-mask/173477#173477) and [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/cryptomate-matte-edge-imperfection/1189344/3) related to finally getting rid of the nasty edge colors when using mattes and compositing, but would like to add to this post relating to the OP's question about edge anti-aliasing. If you use the methods described by vklidu, but also by [this YouTube video by CG Cookie](https://youtu.be/8Pn6C4ZDjd8) using Inpaint nodes and inverse masking etc, you should have practical and near total control of edge sharpness AND get rid of those nasty unwanted edge colors. I have attached a node setup for this:
[image]
Also, a word of caution: you will see a difference in edge quality for Cryptomatte (but NOT ID Mask, as of 2.82a) based upon Cycles Render Properties>Film>Pixel Filter settings. The Cryptomatte will automatically match the sharpness of your pixel filter settings / overall render, so essentially down to a style choice, but be warned that softer edges (like with depth of field and motion blur) can be very challenging to matte and even Inpaint out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any decent way. That is why cryptomatte became "game changer" (with some issues as well, as you can see in your screen). You can play with edge in compositor, but it always brings some artefacts (inaccuracy) in final comp.

[image]

Short pixel "steps" can be disolved quite easily, but long pixel "steps" can't (as you can see on vertical edge). Also corners became a bit chewy. I used ColorRamp instead of Delite/Erode, because it was easier to adjust edge.

[image]

Ad Cryptomatte - in Fusion, there seems to be a way of node tree that can avoid that. So probably someone can bring it into a blender as well. https://blenderartists.org/t/cryptomate-matte-edge-imperfection/1189344/3